# Is there a better way to return the list of prime numbers in given list of numbers

Tags: lisp, racket

I know it should be simple. but I am new to this language and the syntax is kind hard to figure out.

I have made one function to check whether it's the prime number or not, and bigger function would just create the list with only prime numbers.

Input is the any given list of numbers. Let's say '(2 3 7 8 4) Then it only should return '(2 3 7)

So I already have checked whether my primeHelper is working or not just calling primehelper with different numbers.

```
(define (primeHelper x i)
  (cond
    ((<= x 1) #f)
    ((= x 2) #t)
    ((= x 3) #t) 
    ((zero? (modulo x i)) #f)
    ((not(zero? (modulo x i))) #t) 
    (else (primeHelper x (+ i 1)))))

(define (prime lis)
  (cond
    ((null? lis) (display "() list"))
    ((not(list? lis)) (display "this is an atom"))
    ((eq? (primeHelper (car lis) 2) #t)(cons (car lis) '()))
    (else (prime (cdr lis)))
    ))
```

I am just getting a list 2

Comment: If you're only getting `2`, then there *must* be a better way. Specifically, *any* way that gives you the right answer is better than a way that gives you the wrong answer, however fast the latter may be :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems in your program.

First, `primeHelper` is wrong. Try it for instance with `(primeHelper 33 2)`: it will return #t, but 33 is not a prime number.

Here is a correct version (with a recursive function):

```
(define (primeHelper x i)
  (cond ((<= x 1) #f)
        ((= x 2) #t)
        ((>= i x) #t)
        ((zero? (modulo x i)) #f)
        (else (primeHelper x (+ i 1)))))
```

Also, the `prime` function is wrong, its recursion is not correct. Here is a possible correct version:

```
(define (prime lis)
  (cond ((null? lis) '())
        ((primeHelper (car lis) 2) (cons (car lis) (prime (cdr lis))))
        (else (prime (cdr lis)))))
```

Let’s try it:

```
(prime '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23))
'(2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23)
```